# How to hide structure view of files in JetBrain IDE?

Tags: jetbrains-ide

Sometimes I think the structure view of files messed up the view in the project explorer, especially when you have many classes or functions in each file.   How to hide the structure view?[image: quicklook]

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project button on the left, uncheck `Show members`.

It saves your eyes on big projects.

[image: quickview]